# Where to execute method to persist locale change in nuxt-i18n?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I'm following the documentation on how to change the language (https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/lang-switcher.html), which works just fine. But whenever I set `detectBrowserLanguage.useCookie` and `detectBrowserLanguage.alwaysRedirect` in my `nuxt.config.js` to true I should call the `this.$i18n.setLocaleCookie(locale)` method to persist the change (as the documentation tells).

My only question is, where should I call this method?

My current code:

```
<nuxt-link
  class="px-6 py-2 block"
  :click="this.$i18n.setLocaleCookie(locale)"
  v-for="locale in availableLocales"
  :key="locale.code"
  :to="switchLocalePath(locale.code)">{{ locale.code.toUpperCase() }}
```

```
export default {
  computed: {
    availableLocales () {
      return this.$i18n.locales.filter(i => i.code !== this.$i18n.locale)
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see i tried running `this.$i18n.setLocaleCookie(locale)` on the click event of the link but i'm getting `Cannot read property '$i18n' of undefined`

Comment: Stop using this in your template and it should work and also click is an event so not ":" but "@"

Answer (score -1):

Try call it in plugin

```
export default async function ({app, store}) {
  // on change locale
  app.i18n.beforeLanguageSwitch = (oldLocale, newLocale) => {
    ...
  }
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/i18n.js'
  ],
```